# A style I defined in a resource dictionary won't resolve

Tags: wpf, resources, border

So I added a resource dictionary to a resources folder in my project called Styles.xaml like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Resources">

<Style x:Key="groupBoxHeader"
       TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius"
            Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="5 1 5 1" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground"
            Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize"
            Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight"
            Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

But when I try to bind it to a style property of a border like so:

```
Style="{StaticResource groupBoxHeader}"
```

it says "the resource 'groupBoxHeader' could not be resolved". Why is this happening?

Comment: It's a scope issue. You have to merge the resource into any `ResourceDictionary` of the page (scope) you are  referencing the `Style` from. [Microsoft Docs: Merged Resource Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/merged-resource-dictionaries) or move the `Style` to App.xaml (which is globally available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to add the code to merge the resource in the App.xaml file as below.
(I assume the name of your resource file is StyleResource.xaml and it is in the Resources folder.)

// In the App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StyleResource.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If you hate this way then replace StaticResource keyword to the DynamicResource keyword.